# I want to dynamically create a tag by using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using a bootstrap modal.
The Function what I want to dynamically create a button at body tag when I click the modal button.
[Description about function what I apply: As soon as I click the bluebutton, I want to create it at the body tag('beside the '+' button')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ8tZ.png)

```
       window.onlaod = function(){
                var blue = document.getElementById('blue');

                blue.onclick = function(){
                    blue.onclick = null;

                    var result = document.getElementById('result');
                    var newblue = document.createElement('span');
                    newblue.id = 'newblue';
                    newblue.innerHTML += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnWH " id="blue"></button>';

                    result.appendChild(newblue);
                };
            };

    -> This is the code about event after click the bluebutton.


        <!-- label color -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnWH " id="blue"></button>


          </div>

    -> This is the code about bluebutton.



        <div class="card border-secondary mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
            <div class="card-header">Header</div>
                <div class="card-body">



                <div id="result">
                    <span id="first">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary plusbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal"> +
                        </button>
                </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

-> This is the code about '+'button.
```

Comment: This helps? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: Thank you for comment. but contents in link is the thing I already tried it..

Comment: There might be better ways to do this than 'createNode' or 'createElement'?

Answer (score 0):

This will create a button when click on add button inside div id of result code as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="blue">add</button>
    <div id="result"></div> 
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            return addEvent();
        }

        function addEvent() {
            var blueButton = document.getElementById('blue');

            blueButton.addEventListener("click", addButton)
        }

        function addButton() {
            var result = document.getElementById('result');
            var newBtn = document.createElement('span');

            newBtn.id = 'newblue';
            newBtn.innerHTML += '<button type="button" id="blue">test</button>';

            result.appendChild(newBtn);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```